# Error when updating wxmplot graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, wxmpl

I am trying to create a graph that updates dynamically using wxmplot in Python 3.6. According to the documentation here: http://cars.uchicago.edu/software/python/wxmplot/plotpanel.html#plotpanel.plot, I should be calling the update_line function which allows for faster graph updates compared to redrawing the plot. However, this function is not working for me. Here is my code:

```
    import wx
    import random
    from wxmplot import PlotPanel

    class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(1200, 900))

            self.panel_1 = Panel_one(self)
            self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, label='update graph', size=(100, 30))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click_button, self.button_1)
            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            sizer.Add(self.panel_1, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
            sizer.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
            self.SetSizer(sizer)

        def click_button(self, e):
            x.append(max(x)+1)
            y.append(random.randint(0, 10))
            self.panel_1.graph1.update_line(max(x), x, y)

    class Panel_one(wx.Panel):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

            self.graph1 = PlotPanel(self, size=(400, 400))
            self.graph1.plot(x, y)


    x = [0, 1, 2]
    y = [5, 8, 4]

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = wx.App(redirect=False)
        frame = MainFrame(None)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

The idea is for the graph to update whenever the button is clicked with a new data point randomly being generated. I get an error that says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'min'. I am not sure what I did wrong, but I think it may have to do with the update_line function wanting 3 pieces of information: my x and y vectors and a trace. From my understanding, the trace is the  index of the line that needs to be updated, but I am not sure if I did this correctly. Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Edit:

```
    import wx
    import random
    import numpy as np
    from wxmplot import PlotPanel

    class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size=(1200, 900))

            self.x = np.array([0, 1, 2])
            self.y = np.array([5, 8, 4])

            self.panel_1 = Panel_one(self)
            self.panel_1.graph1.plot(self.x, self.y)
            self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, label='update graph', size=(100, 30))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click_button, self.button_1)
            sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
            sizer.Add(self.panel_1, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
            sizer.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.LEFT, 5)
            self.SetSizer(sizer)

        def click_button(self, e):
            self.x = np.append(self.x, [max(self.x)+1])
            self.y = np.append(self.y, [random.randint(0, 10)])
            self.panel_1.graph1.update_line(max(self.x), self.x, self.y)
            self.Layout()

    class Panel_one(wx.Panel):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)

            self.graph1 = PlotPanel(self, size=(400, 400))

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = wx.App(redirect=False)
        frame = MainFrame(None)
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I've never heard of wxmplot but it seems rather unnecessary. Just embedd your plot in wxpython. See [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx2.html).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest if you've never heard of it, you won't know what features it has and why it might be useful.  Even a quick read of the code in the example you point to with the example here should show you that a lot of code (create figure, add subplot, create canvas) is replaced by creating a single PlotPanel.  A wxmplot.PlotPanel also provides richer interaction and customization after the figure is drawn than the NavigationToolbar gives.  Dismissing something you have never heard of as "rather unnecessary"  sort of combines arrogance and ignorance, and ignores the actual question.

Comment: @MNewville Fair point, however my experience is that every single package which tries to wrap matplotlib cuts important features from it. And in most cases it's really worth spending some extra lines but have the original matplotlib functionality. Apart, people writing wrappers could just spend their effort improving matplotlib directly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The user asked about using a library.  Your comment was to tell them to *not* use that library: If someone asked "I'm having trouble reading CSV data into Pandas" do you add a comment of "just use the csv module"?  I sure hope not.  If you don't know what a library does, why are you telling people to not use it, and why are you also saying it shouldn't exist?  You have no idea what you are talking about.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The x and y data should be numpy arrays.

Comment: I'm not sure why that was downvoted.  It is the solution to the question asked about the `AttributeError` raised.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Last question and I'll stop bugging you: Do you know if I am using the update_line function correctly? I no longer get an error, but my graph does not get updated with the new data points being created. I'll edit my original post with my code.

Comment: @JohnDoe, I think you probably want to `update_line()` with trace=0 if you only have one line trace that you're trying to plot.   That is, the trace index is there for situations where you want to update two curves on the same plot.  I think that you are trying to update only 1 curve -- in that case, just use index of 0.